# Bolzano and Cauchy's proof of Intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, math-history

I am not sure if it is the right place to ask, but I have been searching for the proof of Intermediate value theorem made by Bolzano and by Cauchy and I am a bit confused because as I understood it the theorem was first proven by Bolzano and then Cauchy provided a proof of the theorem few years later and it was not the same proof. But where can I find the proofs of the theorem?

Comment: Might be of interest: *[A translation of Bolzano's paper on the intermediate value theorem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0315086080900361)* and *[Stuck in the Middle: Cauchy’s Intermediate Value Theorem and the History of Analytic Rigor](https://www.ams.org/notices/201310/rnoti-p1334.pdf)* (full issue [here](https://www.ams.org/notices/201310/index.html)).

Comment: Cauchy's proof is sketched on [p. 190 of Grabiner's Who Gave You the Epsilon?](https://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/who-gave-you-the-epsilon-cauchy-and-the-origins-of-rigorous-calculus) But the subdivision proof goes back to Stevin and predates both Bolzano and Cauchy by over two centuries, see [Stevin Numbers and Reality](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10699-011-9228-9).

Comment: Also, if you can read french, Cauchy's complete works may be found [here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&collapsing=disabled&query=dc.relation%20all%20%22cb302073189%22&rk=128756;0).

Answer (score 1):

Proof by Bolzano is in Steve Russ - The mathematical works of Bernard Bolzano-Oxford University Press (2004), page 250.

Proof by Cauchy is in Robert E. Bradley, C. Edward Sandifer (auth.) - Cauchy’s Cours d’analyse_ An Annotated Translation-Springer-Verlag New York, (2009) page 32.